# Double or more value inserted when insert query written inside another query result object

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I have the code below which was written in php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$sql = "SELECT * from table name";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

 //the result count is 95142

 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   $sql = "insert into table1 (column) values ('test')";
   $result = $conn->query($sql);
 }
 $conn->close();
?>
```

Which inserting more than 100 000 data in table1  but if I try to limit the source query up to 30 000 it inserts correct count of data into table1.

i.e

```
$sql = "SELECT * from table name limit 10000";
```

Both the table are in same Database.

Even tried with mysql_connect & mysql_query() method also getting the same error. Also tried with another connection for insert query but issue exists.

If I try the code like this

```
$flag = 1;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 $flag = $flag + 1;
}
echo $flag;
```

I am getting the result of 95142.

Comment: Try assigning the result of the `insert` statement to another variable.

Answer (score 0):

you must really use different variable names in the second query !!!

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$sql2 = "insert into table1 (column) values ('test')";
$result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
}
```

and secondly,  delete the previous rows before running script, and then check the count, it must work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Change your variable name `$result` inside the `while`.

Ex:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     $insertSQL = "insert into table1 (column) values ('test')";
     $insertRow = $conn->query($insertSQL);
}
```

The value of `$result` has been changed when insert query is executed. Maybe this is main problem.

Comment: I have also tried assigning the insert query result in different variable but issue exist.

Comment: Hi captain_a, I have tried with a different variable also even removed variable assigning of the return value.  I can't delete the previous rows, because I need the rows for future use. i.e the initial query will be join query to get values from different tables.